# How to align paragraph in XSl FO PDF

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to align a paragraph below in XSL fO.

Label :   value

> ```
>        Be careful not to set the heap size too large, as whatever
>        you allocate reduces the amount of memory available to the
>        operating system and other programs, which could cause 
>        excessive paging (memory swapped back and forth between 
>        RAM and the swap disc, which will slow your system down)
> ```

with proper alignment and indentation. Am able to create with word-breaks but indentation is missing .can anyone suggest the solution

Comment: Please state what alignment and indentation you want to achieve. Please also include your current XSL-FO markup to show what you have currently tried.

Comment: Hi, Have tried this <fo:block  text-indent="5mm"
    font-family="verdana" font-size="12pt"
    space-before="5mm" space-after="5mm"  keep-together="always"/>
indenation as above mentioned all the lines should start from same position

Comment: for better understanding can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050517/paragraph-alignment-in-fo-xsl

Comment: Please add your source xml , the xslt you use, the current outcome en the desired outcome

Comment: I already edited that other question to try to separate out the code blocks. Please add your sample markup as a code block in the question. (Use the '<>' button in the Stack Overflow editor's toolbar to add a code block.) Note that `text-indent` affects only the first line of a block (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#text-indent) and that `keep-together="always"` says to keep everything together on the same line, in the same column, and on the same page. You may instead want `keep-together.within-column="always"`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keep-together)

Answer (score 0):

Think you something like this?

```
<fo:block text-align="justify" margin-left="1.5cm">Your text here ...</fo:block>
```

Or you can use `linefeed-treatment` `white-space-treatment`, `whitespace-collapse` attributes together for preformatted texts.

And you can drop the `fo:block` into a `fo:block-container` for background coloring and bordering.

```
<fo:block margin-left="5mm" margin-right="5mm"
    font-family="verdana" font-size="12pt"
    space-before="5mm" space-after="5mm" keep-together="always"
    linefeed-treatment="preserve" whitespace-treatment="pre" whitespace-collapse="false">
Your multiline
code here,
and more lines,
    with multiple spaces on start   and within
and empty lines ...
        
</fo:block>
```